# Why don't people use multi-layer helical primary coils when building tesla coils?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I've seen helical coils, Archimedes spirals, and pancake primary coils on Tesla Coils, but I've never seen anyone use a coil like the one in this calculator - http://coil32.net/online-calculators/multilayer-coil-calculator.html

Is there a reason for this or is it just less convenient?

Answer (score 1):

Tesla coils are designed to create very high voltage. Consequently there is high voltage across each turn. This has to be kept below the electric breakdown voltage, otherwise the coil will be destroyed.

If one wants to get a coil that has as much voltage as possible per each turn, one must continue winding the coil in one direction only. If one took the wire off the high turn end of the pipe, lead it back down and wind it around on top of the low turns, there would be too high a voltage between the turns and an electric breakdown would result.

Comment: But sufficient resistance between the high and low voltage wraps would prevent breakdown, correct?

Comment: If one wanted to have a multilayer coil, that would be possible, but the layers would have to be isolated very well, by a thick layer of material that has high resistance to electrical breakdown.